# Python - regex.match and different text codecs?

Tags: python, utf-8, utf-16

I am working with a Python script that needs to scan automatically generated .log files and identify a whether a .log file contains a certain string of text. Unfortunately, the generated .log files have characters of different codecs ranging from utf-8, utf-16, and ISO-8859-1.

This is a chunk of the code that describes the functionality:

```
with open(os.path.join(log_directory, file), 'r', encoding="utf-16") as f:
        content = f.read()
        for c in content.split('\n'):
            x = regex.match(r'.*"running([^"]*)".*', c, re.IGNORECASE)
```

For example, for some .log files, utf-8 works fine, but I occasionally get `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`.

I then tried utf-16 which ends up working better, but then I occasionally get `'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x22 in position 52: truncated data` or `UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM`.

I then tried ISO-8859-1. I get no more errors there, but the script can no longer parse through the file and identify if a certain string exists.

Comment: There's no general solution to the problem of decoding files with unknown encodings.  If you don't know the encoding in advance you just have to guess, or use a tools like _chardet_ to guess for you.

Comment: Thanks, I would mark this as an answer if possible. What I ended up doing was getting the team involved in creating these .log files to change the outputs to a known encoding. Chardet is interesting, and I can definitely use that for another project.

Comment: I suspect that; _the byte `0xff` in position 0_ that there is a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) _inside_ the file. Check `with open(file,'rb') as f: xx=f.read(); print(xx)` whether there are more occurrences of `\xff\xfe`…